# Mac verify failure on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, web, passbook

I am getting an error with my ruby on rails application.

I am trying to use this repository :https://github.com/nomad/dubai to generate a pkpass.

However, I am getting a pcks12Error::Mac verify failure at this step:

```
Dubai::Passbook.certificate, Dubai::Passbook.password = "/resources/certificate.p12", "mypassword"

# Example.pass is a directory with files "pass.json", "icon.png" & "icon@2x.png"
File.open("Example.pkpass", 'w') do |f|
  f.write Dubai::Passbook::Pass.new("Example.pass").pkpass.string
end
```

I looked on the web but founded nothing about this kind of error in RoR.

EDIT:
I am pretty sure that this is an OpenSSL error. My certificates are coming from another machine. Is that thing can influence this error? Do I have to create a certificate on my machine? To configure OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the answer by myself.
In the Dubai gem, you just have to change the read() by a binread(). 
It solved my mac verify failure.